# Socialmedia buttons aligned different in mobile browser, but normal if desktop version requested

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following problem a website i am working at:
-I have a Twitter, Facebook and G+ button at the top-right of the page.
-They are aligned in one line.
 

-When i watch the website at my smartphone or tablet, the facebook button appears in an new line.
The website is fully responsive, so everythings size change by resizing the window, but the buttons always stay aligned (except mobile browsers).

Images: [The buttons aligned](http://postimg.org/image/v0u6ya6fj/) 
 [The images with a mobile browser](http://postimg.org/image/iapyl6yhb/)

The socialmedia buttons in "share.php":

```
<g:plusone href="http://www.example.fr" size="tall" annotation="none">           </g:plusone>
<script type="text/javascript" id="plusonescript">
window.___gcfg = {lang: 'fr'};
(function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
    var s = document.getElementById('plusonescript'); s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
</script>
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.example.fr" data-lang="fr" data-count="none">Tweeter</a>
<script>
!function(d,s,id){
    var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
    if(!d.getElementById(id)){
        js=d.createElement(s);
        js.id=id;
        js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}
    }
    (document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
</script>
 <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example.fr" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false" style="vertical-align:top; height:20px;"></div>
```

I all have this in one div "index.php":

```
<?php include "like_button.php"; ?>
    <div id="container">
    <header>
        <div style="float:right"><?php include "share.php"; ?></div>
        <h1>example</h1>    
    </header>
```

The "like_button.php":

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And the style of the twitter button:

```
.twitter-share-button[style] { vertical-align: top !important;}
```

I really stuck at this problem and dont now what to do anymore, i would really appreciate any tips, ideas or solutions :)

The html output from the Desktop:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="description" content="example">
    <meta name="exampler" content="example">
    <meta name="example">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script> <!-- Includes scripts and stylesheets -->
    <title>example</title>
    <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-47894518-1', 'example.fr');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>  <div id="container">
    <header>
         <div style="float:right;"><g:plusone href="http://www.example.fr" size="tall" annotation="none"></g:plusone>
    <script type="text/javascript" id="plusonescript">
    window.___gcfg = {lang: 'fr'};
    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
        var s = document.getElementById('plusonescript'); s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
    </script>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.example.fr" data-lang="fr" data-count="none">Tweeter</a>
    <script>
    !function(d,s,id){
        var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
        if(!d.getElementById(id)){
            js=d.createElement(s);
            js.id=id;
            js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}
        }
        (document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
    </script>
     <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example.fr" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false" style="vertical-align:top; height:20px;"></div></div>
            <h1>example</h1>
    </header> 
    <nav>
<ul>
    <li> <a href="example" title="lexample">Accueil</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="example" title="example">Prestations</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="example" title="example">Plan d’accès</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="example" title="Contacter nous">Contact</a> </li>
</ul>
</nav>  <article>
        <style>
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
article h1
    {mso-style-link:"�berschrift 1 Zchn";
    margin-top:24.0pt;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    page-break-after:avoid;
    font-size:16.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#345A8A;}
article h3
    {mso-style-link:"�berschrift 3 Zchn";
    margin-top:10.0pt;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    page-break-after:avoid;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#4F81BD;}
article h4
    {mso-style-link:"�berschrift 4 Zchn";
    margin-top:10.0pt;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    page-break-after:avoid;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#4F81BD;
    font-style:italic;}
article a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;}
article a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {color:purple;
    text-decoration:underline;}
article p.MsoListParagraph, li.MsoListParagraph, div.MsoListParagraph
    {margin-top:0cm;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:36.0pt;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
p.MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst, li.MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst, div.MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst
    {margin-top:0cm;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:36.0pt;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
p.MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle, li.MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle, div.MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle
    {margin-top:0cm;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:36.0pt;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
p.MsoListParagraphCxSpLast, li.MsoListParagraphCxSpLast, div.MsoListParagraphCxSpLast
    {margin-top:0cm;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:36.0pt;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
span.berschrift1Zchn
    {mso-style-name:"�berschrift 1 Zchn";
    mso-style-link:"�berschrift 1";
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#345A8A;
    font-weight:bold;}
span.berschrift3Zchn
    {mso-style-name:"�berschrift 3 Zchn";
    mso-style-link:"�berschrift 3";
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#4F81BD;
    font-weight:bold;}
span.berschrift4Zchn
    {mso-style-name:"�berschrift 4 Zchn";
    mso-style-link:"�berschrift 4";
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#4F81BD;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
@page WordSection1
    {size:595.0pt 842.0pt;
    margin:70.85pt 70.85pt 70.85pt 70.85pt;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
 /* List Definitions */
 ol
    {margin-bottom:0cm;}
ul
    {margin-bottom:0cm;}
</style>
example
    </article> 
    <footer>
</footer>    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the source from the mobile browser (also if it should not be different):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="description" content="example">
    <meta name="author" content="example">
    <meta name="keywords" content="example">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script> <!-- Includes scripts and stylesheets -->
    <title>Accueil | example</title>
    <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-47894518-1', 'example');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>  <div id="container">
    <header>
         <div style="float:right;"><g:plusone href="http://example" size="tall" annotation="none"></g:plusone>
    <script type="text/javascript" id="plusonescript">
    window.___gcfg = {lang: 'fr'};
    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
        var s = document.getElementById('plusonescript'); s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
    </script>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.example" data-lang="fr" data-count="none">Tweeter</a>
    <script>
    !function(d,s,id){
        var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
        if(!d.getElementById(id)){
            js=d.createElement(s);
            js.id=id;
            js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}
        }
        (document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
    </script>
     <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example.fr" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false" style="vertical-align:top; height:20px;"></div></div>
            <h1>example</h1>
    </header> 
    <nav>
<ul>
    <li> <a href="example" title="examplel">Accueil</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="example" title="example">Prestations</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="example" title="example">Plan d’accès</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="example" title="example">Contact</a> </li>
</ul>
</nav>  <article>
        <style>
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
article h1
    {mso-style-link:"�berschrift 1 Zchn";
    margin-top:24.0pt;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    page-break-after:avoid;
    font-size:16.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#345A8A;}
article h3
    {mso-style-link:"�berschrift 3 Zchn";
    margin-top:10.0pt;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    page-break-after:avoid;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#4F81BD;}
article h4
    {mso-style-link:"�berschrift 4 Zchn";
    margin-top:10.0pt;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    page-break-after:avoid;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#4F81BD;
    font-style:italic;}
article a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;}
article a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {color:purple;
    text-decoration:underline;}
article p.MsoListParagraph, li.MsoListParagraph, div.MsoListParagraph
    {margin-top:0cm;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:36.0pt;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
p.MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst, li.MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst, div.MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst
    {margin-top:0cm;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:36.0pt;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
p.MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle, li.MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle, div.MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle
    {margin-top:0cm;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:36.0pt;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
p.MsoListParagraphCxSpLast, li.MsoListParagraphCxSpLast, div.MsoListParagraphCxSpLast
    {margin-top:0cm;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:36.0pt;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
span.berschrift1Zchn
    {mso-style-name:"�berschrift 1 Zchn";
    mso-style-link:"�berschrift 1";
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#345A8A;
    font-weight:bold;}
span.berschrift3Zchn
    {mso-style-name:"�berschrift 3 Zchn";
    mso-style-link:"�berschrift 3";
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#4F81BD;
    font-weight:bold;}
span.berschrift4Zchn
    {mso-style-name:"�berschrift 4 Zchn";
    mso-style-link:"�berschrift 4";
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#4F81BD;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
@page WordSection1
    {size:595.0pt 842.0pt;
    margin:70.85pt 70.85pt 70.85pt 70.85pt;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
 /* List Definitions */
 ol
    {margin-bottom:0cm;}
ul
    {margin-bottom:0cm;}
</style>
example
    </article> 
    <footer>
</footer>    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your social media buttons have run out of available space to all sit horizontally on the mobile platform.

I would suggest using some CSS media queries to adjust the layout for your mobile platform.

For example, you could use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and then a media query like:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
 //add your mobile styles here
}
```

That would cover some mobile devices, but without seeing the output html its tricky to give a complete answer for you. Hope that helps.

----- UPDATE ----

Ok, I have made a couple of changes for you so that this now works.

Firstly, I have added a new class to your container div that has your social media icons:

```
<div class="social-media" style="float:right;">
```

Next I have added the following media query into your styles. I have had to override the inline styles with "!important". Add the following into your `<style>` tag:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {

 .social-media .fb_iframe_widget{

    /* this prevents the facebook link from stretching across the page, taking up valuable space */
    width:50px!important;
 }

 .social-media .twitter-share-button{
    float:left;
 }

 .social-media > div,
 .social-media > iframe{
    float:left!important;
    margin-right:5px!important;
 }

}
```

So they are the main changes. However, I noticed that the code on the page was a bit messed up, so I have re-positioned some things like moving the styles inside the `<head>` tag. Here is the complete solution for you, tested on an iPhone:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="description" content="example">
    <meta name="author" content="example">
    <meta name="keywords" content="example">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <!-- Includes scripts and stylesheets -->
    <title>example</title>
    <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-47894518-1', 'example');
      ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>

    <style>

@media (max-width: 480px) {

 .social-media .fb_iframe_widget{


    width:50px!important;
 }

 .social-media .twitter-share-button{
    float:left;
 }

 .social-media > div,
 .social-media > iframe{
    float:left!important;
    margin-right:5px!important;
 }

}


p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
article h1
    {mso-style-link:"�berschrift 1 Zchn";
    margin-top:24.0pt;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    page-break-after:avoid;
    font-size:16.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#345A8A;}
article h3
    {mso-style-link:"�berschrift 3 Zchn";
    margin-top:10.0pt;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    page-break-after:avoid;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#4F81BD;}
article h4
    {mso-style-link:"�berschrift 4 Zchn";
    margin-top:10.0pt;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    page-break-after:avoid;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#4F81BD;
    font-style:italic;}
article a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;}
article a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {color:purple;
    text-decoration:underline;}
article p.MsoListParagraph, li.MsoListParagraph, div.MsoListParagraph
    {margin-top:0cm;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:36.0pt;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
p.MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst, li.MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst, div.MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst
    {margin-top:0cm;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:36.0pt;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
p.MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle, li.MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle, div.MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle
    {margin-top:0cm;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:36.0pt;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
p.MsoListParagraphCxSpLast, li.MsoListParagraphCxSpLast, div.MsoListParagraphCxSpLast
    {margin-top:0cm;
    margin-right:0cm;
    margin-bottom:0cm;
    margin-left:36.0pt;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
span.berschrift1Zchn
    {mso-style-name:"�berschrift 1 Zchn";
    mso-style-link:"�berschrift 1";
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#345A8A;
    font-weight:bold;}
span.berschrift3Zchn
    {mso-style-name:"�berschrift 3 Zchn";
    mso-style-link:"�berschrift 3";
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#4F81BD;
    font-weight:bold;}
span.berschrift4Zchn
    {mso-style-name:"�berschrift 4 Zchn";
    mso-style-link:"�berschrift 4";
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:#4F81BD;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Cambria","serif";}
@page WordSection1
    {size:595.0pt 842.0pt;
    margin:70.85pt 70.85pt 70.85pt 70.85pt;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
 /* List Definitions */
 ol
    {margin-bottom:0cm;}
ul
    {margin-bottom:0cm;}
</style>



</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    <div id="container">
        <header>
            <div class="social-media" style="float:right;">
                <g:plusone href="http://www.example.fr" size="tall" annotation="none"></g:plusone>
                <script type="text/javascript" id="plusonescript">
                window.___gcfg = {lang: 'fr'};
                (function() {
                    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
                    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
                    var s = document.getElementById('plusonescript'); s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
                })();
                </script>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.example.fr" data-lang="fr" data-count="none">Tweeter</a>
                <script>
                !function(d,s,id){
                    var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
                    if(!d.getElementById(id)){
                        js=d.createElement(s);
                        js.id=id;
                        js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
                        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}
                    }
                    (document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
                </script>
                <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example.fr" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false" style="vertical-align:top; height:20px;"></div>
            </div>
            <h1>example</h1>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="example" title="example">Accueil</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="example" title="example">Prestations</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="example" title="example">Plan d’accès</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contacter.php" title="Contacter nous">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <article>
            </article>
            <footer></footer>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Just as an added note, there are some strange chars coming out in the CSS from your original post:

```
{mso-style-link:"�berschrift 4 Zchn";
```

So the bit that is a "�".

Just make sure you get rid of those as well ;)

Comment: thank you for your fast answer :-)  i already have a meta with: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> what is the initial scale for? The idea with the media query is good, but i dont know what to change, because everything gets calculated by a jquery script, relative to the screen dimensions. The i dont understand is, when select the checkbox "Desktop-Version" everything is displayed correctly. How can i show the output html without pasting an URL which can be found by google?

Comment: If you can do a "view source" on the webpage and paste it into here for both desktop and mobile versions, then we can see what the html looks like. Then we can see what is available to apply different styles to via the media query. :)

Comment: Ok, i posted the code into the main question at the end

Comment: Just updated my original answer for you. That should solve your problem.

Comment: hey thank you very much! that is working great at my mobile, just the same problem at my tablet. Do you think i can use the changes for all screen sizes, or do i have to add some special media querys?

Comment: Glad that's helped :). If you want it to work for tablets as well, you just need a few more sets of media queries to cater for their screen sizes. Have a look at how bootstrap2 use theirs. http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a specified width to your div including your share.php data.

```
<header>
        <div style="float:right;width:200px;"><?php include "share.php"; ?></div>
        <h1>example</h1> 
    </header>
```

Comment: i already tried that, but that only moves the bunch of links to the left